# Why does my smart contract method fail when called via Web3.js with more than one argument?

Tags: web3js

**Observation(s):**

- When calling a compiled smart contract method via Web3.js, my contract method `createOrder` succeeds when the method *only* accepts (1) argument.
- Upon updating and re-compiling the smart contract method such that the method requires (2) arguments, calling the method with the required 2 arguments produces an error: `Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert.

**Expectation(s):**

- I expect for the contract method `createOrder` to be executed successfully without error(s) when the method is supplied with arguments of the correct number and appropriate type.
- I expect a new transaction to be created and for the `ReceivedWebOrder` event to be recorded with the arguments specified.

**Notes(s):**

- The contract executes *as expected* when plugged into the Remix online IDE. To me, this suggests I'm not calling the Web.js method correctly

**System Info:**

- Web3 version: 1.2.1
- Node version: 12.10.0
- Truffle version: 5.1.32
- Ganache version: 2.4.0
- Platform: MacOS Mojave (10.14.6)

**Smart Contract**

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.7.0;

import "../lib/safemath.sol";

contract CuizzineWebOrder {

    event ReceivedWebOrder(string order_id, string customer_id);

    struct WebOrder {
        string order_id;
        string customer_id;
        string restaurant_id;
        address customerWalletAddress;
        address restaurantWalletAddress;
        uint256 totalETH;
    }

    function createOrder(string memory order_id, string memory customer_id)
        public
    {
        emit ReceivedWebOrder(order_id, customer_id);
    }
}
```

**Web3.js Code**

```
/** DEPENDENCIES */
const contractABI = require("./build/contracts/CuizzineWebOrder.json").abi;
const contractAddress = "0x0b82152Cc62e15Bd390649eCe96c170fc7375FBf";

/** APPLICATION */
(async function myApp({ contractABI, contractAddress }) {
    const Web3 = require("web3");
    const myWeb3 = new Web3();
    const wsProvider = new myWeb3.providers.WebsocketProvider("ws://localhost:7545");
    myWeb3.setProvider(wsProvider);
    const myContract = await new myWeb3.eth.Contract(contractABI, contractAddress);
    const [customerWalletAddress, restaurantWalletAddress] = await myWeb3.eth.getAccounts();

    const myWebOrder = {
        customerWalletAddress,
        restaurantWalletAddress,
        order_id: "XEO1reMLnJhlf7JcZNJB",
        customer_id: "UUCzbG5zdZ6VS4oPQyJK",
        restaurant_id: "8KbG1mFLeCMGSDZyEnL4",
        totalETH: myWeb3.utils.toWei("0.10082464543958122")
    };

    try {
        myContract.events.ReceivedWebOrder()
            .on("data", onReceivedWebOrder)
            .on("error", onError);

        const result = await myContract.methods.createOrder(myWebOrder.order_id, myWebOrder.customer_id).send({
            from: customerWalletAddress
        });
        process.exit(0);
    } catch (e) {
        console.warn("⚠️  Ensure you are CONNECTED to a test network. If using Ganache, verify the workspace is configured properly.");
        onError(e);
    }

    function onReceivedWebOrder(data) {
        const { order_id } = data.returnValues;
        console.info(order_id);
    }

    function onError(error) {
        console.error(error);
        process.exit(1);
    }

}({
    contractABI,
    contractAddress
}));
```

Comment: Which method has changed from taking 1 argument to 2 arguments? Which line of JS code is throwing the error?

Comment: `Upon updating and re-compiling the smart contract method` - have you also redeployed the smart contract?

Comment: `const contractAddress = "0x0b82152Cc62e15Bd390649eCe96c170fc7375FBf";` suggests you haven't, so why are you expecting this to work???

Comment: It might be that the default gas is not enough, try increasing to something like 100k, or 1m gas.

Comment: @goodvibration `myContract.methods.createOrder`, throws the error. I have indeed re-deployed the contract. The `contractAddress` shown is the address of the contract defined in the ABI after the contract is compiled. At which point I deploy Why does this value suggest I haven't deployed? Please clarify. Forgot to mention I'm using Truffle with Ganache.